# Python Post request to API

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

this might be a simple question but I couldn't find the problem why I'm not able to call post request to api url. I have cross-check with similar questions but mine still got problem.

This is the script

```
import requests
import json

#API details
url = "http://192.168.1.100:9792/api/scan"
body = {"service":"scan", "user_id":"1", "action":"read_all", "code":"0"}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

#Making http post request
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body, verify=False)
print(response)

#Decode response.json() method to a python dictionary for data process utilization
dictData = response.json()
print(dictData)

with open('scan.json', 'w') as fp:
  json.dump(dictData, fp, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Getting error

```
 raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

print(response) got return

```
<Response [200]>
```

if i run curl like below ok..and it will return the data from api post request

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"service":"scan","user_id":"1","action":"read_all","code":"0"}' http://192.168.1.100:9792/api/scan
```

using curl ok...but when i use requests/json python got problem...I think I might miss something here where I'm not able to detect. Please help and point me the right way. Thank you.

Comment: What does `response.text` contains?

Comment: it give nothing , just blank line...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had similar errors and dumping my data solved the issue. Try passing your body as a dump instead:

```py
import requests
import json

#API details
url = "http://192.168.1.100:9792/api/scan"
body = json.dumps({"service":"scan", "user_id":"1", "action":"read_all", "code":"0"})
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

#Making http post request
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body, verify=False)

print(response.json())
```

Comment: Yes...it works now...but why need to dumps the body data? .... I have working with similar api before and use the same method... but this time..cannot...when dumps the data...resolved the issue. Do know why sir?

Comment: It how Python dictionary is sent as data  to your API and what format the API expects. Dumping forces the dictionary to bytes in a way that is secured for sockets transmission